# disable next previous button in prettyPhoto gallery of jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the pretty gallery slide show to pop up the item. I use one image + one link, not in a group. So I no need to display Next and Previous button on my popup image.

This is the code in my site.master :

```
$('.promotion').attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto[gallery2]');
```

And this is in my user control :

```
<div style="float:left; border:0px!important" id="gallery-block">
<div class="gallery clearfix"> 
<a class="promotion" href="Picturename.jpg">     
<img id="medium-image" src="Picturename.jpg" alt="Product Specification" 
    width="230" />
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone share me, how to disable Next and Previous button in Pretty Photo Gallery?

Comment: You can hide the images from the css.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Common sense says it should not display the prev/next buttons if there is only one image. What image do you see when you click these buttons?

Comment: @DotNetter : Thanks, But I used it in many page, I have pages that used it in group too. That's why I cannot set css to hide that.

Comment: I think there is an automatic slideshow set to 'true' and your buttons are displayed set it to 'false' and it wont display.

Comment: @all : I added more code below. Thanks.

Comment: @SalmanA : It display the image the same we not yet click the next and previous button.

Comment: @titi-just add rel='prettyphoto' in your img tag and replace  'prettyPhoto[gallery2]' with 'prettyphoto'.

Comment: @DotNetter : Thanks, it worked. But it display `undefined` message at the bottom of my popup.

Comment: @titi-You're welcome and check your image path if it has not linked up then you'll be displayed that message.

Comment: @DotNetter : It display the right image, just show a message `Undefined` under my image, while it is popup.

Comment: @titi-There is bug fix here http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/633/prettyphoto-text-link-shows-undefined-as-the-title-how-to-change/p1

Comment: Add this to your Custom CSS field in theme options:

    .pp_nav { display: none !important; }

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Custom CSS field in theme options:

```
.pp_nav { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery.prettyPhoto.js file you can just commented out:

$.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous'); and $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');

Answer (score 0):

Based on version you use, inspect page and extract prev/next buttons classes and Hide them like this:

```
    <style>
    /*  disable next/prev buttons */
    .pp_next {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .pp_previous {
        display: none !important;
    }
    </style>
```

for me button classes are *pp_next* and *pp_previous*